# Highlight level proportionally to number of matching tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

Would it be possible to add different highlights for interesting questions that match favorite tags?

All interesting questions appears with the same yellow color.

For example, I have the mysql tag in favorite, then a question tagged with mysql and, let's say 4 tags I don't have in favorite, will be highlight.

If a question have all its tags matching with mine favorite, I think it would be nice that this question benefit of a more important highlight beacause I have more chance to be able to help.

I'm not a good designer so I don't really propose a way to add different level of highlight, just want to know if something appealing and reflecting the proportionality of matching tags can be done.

PS : I expect that the answer will be no because this kind of feature may involve more treatments for maybe something not enough usefull.

Comment: I think this happens on the client side, if that's the case then it ought to be easy to do, even as an unofficial prototype.